# Make div appear when user scrolls upwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Hey all I was just wondering how I would create an effect on jquery and/or javascript where when the user scrolled upwards, a div would appear.

Thanks!

Comment: show us what you've tried ? is it like a do for me stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a way to detect the `scroll up` event, then the whole process is too easy.

To detect scroll up I have used to below [**approach**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1915211.aspx?scroll%20down%20and%20scroll%20up%20events%20in%20jquery),

> ```
> $(function () {
>     //Keep track of last scroll
>     var lastScroll = 0;
>     $(window).scroll(function (event) {
>         //Sets the current scroll position
>         var st = $(this).scrollTop();
>         //Determines up-or-down scrolling
>         if (st > lastScroll) {
>             //Replace this with your function call for downward-scrolling
>             $('#up').hide();
>         } else {
>             //Replace this with your function call for upward-scrolling
>             $('#up').show();
>         }
>         //Updates scroll position
>         lastScroll = st;
>     });
> });
> ```

Keep a fixed positioned `div` and `hide/show` based on the scroll is what I have done.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x8BPP/2/)